# CSS selector for image in own line

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a CSS selector for `<img>` elements on their own line but not an in-line `<img>`. So it should match (example 1):

`<p><img src="..."></p>`

but not (example 2):

`<p>Lorem <img src="..."> ipsum</p>`

I tried `img:only-child` -- because [if the text is a text node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text#comment116904251_1520469) surely this shouldn't match example 2. But it does.

Why? I want margins for in-line images (example 2) but no margins for images on their own line (example 1).

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you have control of the HTML? If so, why do the standalone images need to be inside a `<p>`? Or you could just add a class for inline vs standalone.

Comment: @DBS Do I have control of the HTML? Not really. This is for a CMS where the images are inserted by an editor. I personally could remove the <p> via the source view but most users couldn't.

Comment: It appears there is no CSS selector to distinguish whether one element contains text and another element so some workaround would be required.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `word-spacing` that will add margin only in your second situation

```css
p {
  word-spacing:50px;
}
```

```html
<p><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/100/100"></p>
<p>Lorem <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/100/100"> ipsum</p>
```

Comment: This only really works when there's a maximum of 1 word on each side of the image, otherwise the word spacing makes a mess of your regular text.

Comment: @DBS *This only really works when there's a maximum of 1 word on each side of the image* --> and this is what the OP is showing in his question

Comment: It is, but I think there's a good chance that was simply to keep the example short.

Comment: @DBS You are correct, this was a trivial example, perhaps too trivial!

Comment: @Temani Afif I am looking to set the img style not the p style, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @DBS that's why people need to make accurate and real examples instead of *simple* one far from their real use cases

Comment: @LeonS. yes too trivial. I am answering based on the question information (Sorry but I cannot read your mind ..)

Answer (score 1):

If you have several words at the start before the image then unfortunately the word-spacing option doesn't really do it for you.

What you can do is position the p element back a bit, position the first letter forward by the same amount and give the image a margin left and right of the same amount.

This will then give you this outcome:
[image]

This may be sufficient for your use case - it's drawback is that the img has a right hand margin in the img-only case. This may or may not matter to you. In the sense this is all within a p element I suspect it'll be OK as any following content will be on a newline.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p::first-letter {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

p {
  margin-left: -20px;
}

p img {
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<p><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/100/100"></p>


<p>More than one word of text <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/100/100">
  </ "> and some more text</p>
```

Comment: Thanks. It's actually the <p> that had l/r margins, so <p>text</p> and <p>text one <img> text two</p> was fine with margins, but for <p><img></p> I wanted no margins on the <p>. Apologies if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think the CSS solutions are good. Especially @AHaworth because it also takes into account when there are more words in the text. Which is very probably the case. Therefore also thumbs up!

For the sake of completeness, I have added a Javascript solution here.

```js
w = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper')

w.forEach((el) => {  
  if (el.childNodes.length > 1) {
    el.childNodes.forEach((e) => {
      if( e.length === undefined) {
        e.classList.add('addMargin')
      }
    })
  }
})
```

```css
.addMargin {
  margin-left:20px;
  margin-right:20px;
}
```

```html
<p class="wrapper"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/100/100"></p>
<p class="wrapper">Lorem <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/100/100"> ipsum bla</p>
<p class="wrapper">Lorem ipsum <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/100/100"> ipsum bla </p>
```